# Is there any more information about David Brin's (derelict) Progenitor fleet?

Tags: uplift-universe

Years ago, I loaned my tattered paperback copy of *Startide Rising* to my boss. It contained mention of a fleet of derelict Progenitor ships.

Did Brin ever write anything that gives us any more information about this fleet?

Comment: IIRC the *Brightness Reef* trilogy has a few passing mentions, in the form of remembrances by the *Streaker* crew (notably Gillian Baskin), but nothing really substantive.